# How can I check the Payload size when using Azure Eventhubs and avoid a PayloadSizeExceededException?

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

So I am getting this exception:

```
com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.PayloadSizeExceededException: Size of the payload exceeded Maximum message size: 256 kb
```

I believe the exception is self explanatory, however, I an not sure what to do about it.

```
private int MAXBYTES = (int) ((1024 * 256) * .8);
for (EHubMessage message : payloads) {
    byte[] payloadBytes = message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
    events.add(sendEvent);
    byteCount += payloadBytes.length;
    if (byteCount > this.MAXBYTES) {
        calls.add(ehc.sendASync(events));
        logs.append("[Size:").append(events.size()).append(" - ").append(byteCount / 1024).append("kb] ");
        events = new LinkedList<EventData>();
        byteCount = 0;
        pushes++;
    }
}
```

I am counting the bytes and such.  I have thought through the UTF-8 thing but I believe that should not matter.  UTF-8 can be more than one byte, but it should be counted correctly with the "getBytes".

I could not find a reliable way to get the bytes in a string and I am not even sure how Azure counts the bytes.  "payload" is a broad statement.  Could include the boilerplate stuff and such.

Any Ideas?  It would be great if there was a

```
EventHubClient.checkPayload(list);
```

method but there doesn't seem to be.  How do you guys check the Payload Size?

Comment: use the `SerializedSizeInBytes` property, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.serializedsizeinbytes?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0.

Comment: @PeterBons Looks like the question was about Java SDK...

Comment: Do you guys know if this uses JSON to transfer the data?  I was wondering if I JSONized the entire EventData object if that would give me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think you need to check the size of the current payload count and a new payload first before you add the new payload into `events`, as below.

```
const int MAXBYTES = 1024 * 256; // not necessary to multiply by .8 
for (EHubMessage message : payloads) {
    byte[] payloadBytes = message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    if (byteCount + payloadBytes.length > this.MAXBYTES) {
        calls.add(ehc.sendASync(events));
        logs.append("[Size:").append(events.size()).append(" - ").append(byteCount / 1024).append("kb] ");
        events = new LinkedList<EventData>();
        byteCount = 0;
        pushes++;
    }
    EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
    events.add(sendEvent);
}
```

If you first added the new event data to count the payload size, it's too late and the data size of events which will be sent that might be exceed the payload limits.

Comment: Yes, I saw this bug and have not fixed it yet.  However, all of our payloads are around 1kb and very uniform.  Have you had experience with this?   My current theory is the entire EventData object is Jsonized.  That would have some overhead to each object.  We do end up sending quite a few objects (since they are small) so any overhead might put us over the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should have added more of the actual code then I did in the original post. Here is what I came up with:

```
private int MAXBYTES = (int) ((1024 * 256) * .9);
for (EHubMessage message : payloads) {
    byte[] payloadBytes = message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int propsSize = message.getProps() == null ? 0 : message.getProps().toString().getBytes().length;
    int messageSize = payloadBytes.length + propsSize;
        if (byteCount + messageSize > this.MAXBYTES) {
            calls.add(ehc.sendASync(events));
            logs.append("[Size:").append(events.size()).append(" - ").append(byteCount / 1024).append("kb] ");
            events = new LinkedList<EventData>();
            byteCount = 0;
            pushes++;
        }
        byteCount += messageSize;
        EventData sendEvent = new EventData(payloadBytes);
        sendEvent.getProperties().putAll(message.getProps());
        events.add(sendEvent);
    }
    if (!events.isEmpty()) {
        calls.add(ehc.sendASync(events));
        logs.append("[Size:").append(events.size()).append(" - ").append(byteCount / 1024).append("kb]");
        pushes++;
    }
    // lets wait til they are done.
    CompletableFuture.allOf(calls.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
}
```

If you notice, I was adding Properties to the EventData but not counting the bytes.  The toString() for a Map returns something like:

```
{markiscool=markiscool}
```

Again, I am not sure of the boilerplate characters that the Azure api is adding but I am sure it is not much.  Notice I still back off the MAXBYTES a bit just in case.

It would still be good to get a "payload size checker" method in the api but I would imagine that it would have to build the payload first to give it back to you.  I experimented with having my EHubMessage object figure this out for me, but "getBytes()" on a String actually does some conversion that I don't want to do twice.